# How to upload the SpeechToText result into an Azure Container?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Cognitive Service Speech To Text to get a transcription for an Azure Blob.

After I'm getting the result, I'm trying to upload this back to another Azure Container.

Service method:

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> TextToSpeech(string subscriptionKey, string region, string text)
{
     var speechTranslateConfig = SpeechTranslationConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);

     using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechTranslateConfig, null);
     var speechSynthesisResult = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);

     using var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(speechSynthesisResult);
     audioDataStream.SetPosition(0);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[16000];

     while (audioDataStream.ReadData(buffer) > 0) ;
     var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

     return stream;
}
```

In Controller, after I'm getting the result, I'm trying to upload the result in another container:

```
var translatedStream = await _speechService.TextToSpeech(_cognitiveServiceConfig.SubscriptionKey, _cognitiveServiceConfig.Region, text);
var translatedStorageFile = new StorageFile() { Stream = translatedStream, Name = $"{fileName}-TRANSLATED", Extension = audioExtension };
var translatedBlobUrl = _azureBlobStorageService.UploadFileAsync(translatedStorageFile, "translated").Result;
```

Upload method:

```
public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(StorageFile storageFile, string container)
{
     var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(_cloudStorageAccountConfig.ConnectionString, container);

     var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{storageFile.Name}.{storageFile.Extension}");
     if (!blobClient.Exists())
     {
          await blobClient.UploadAsync(storageFile.Stream);
     }

     return blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

I think that this part of my code is not working as expected (even if I found this in their documentation) and the stream result is not the correct one:

```
audioDataStream.SetPosition(0);

byte[] buffer = new byte[16000];

while (audioDataStream.ReadData(buffer) > 0) ;
var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

I'm saying this because if I download the result file, it has only 16kb, and can't play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by using `AudioData` from `speechSynthesisResult` and create a stream from this:

```
var buffer = speechSynthesisResult.AudioData;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into this issue is because you're always creating a new instance of `MemoryStream` while reading from `AudioDataStream` and that's why your stream size is 16KB (size of your byte buffer).

Can you try something like the following (untested code though):

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> TextToSpeech(string subscriptionKey, string region, string text)
{
    var speechTranslateConfig = SpeechTranslationConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);

    using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechTranslateConfig, null);
    var speechSynthesisResult = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);

    using var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(speechSynthesisResult);
    audioDataStream.SetPosition(0);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();//Create new memory stream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16000];

    while (audioDataStream.ReadData(buffer) > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer);
    }

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the result is the same. Btw, I don't think that the `MemoryStream` is always instantiated while reading because after the `while` loop I have `;` and only after the loop is finished the `MemoryStream` is declared. Please correct me if I'm wrong.